# How to access index in position method of iter?

Tags: arrays, lambda, rust, iterator

I'm trying to print the first number in the array that isn't exactly `1` greater than the previous number (expected result is `7` in the following example).

I wrote `&n > 0 &&` to avoid checking the (non-existent) number before the first number.

```rust
fn main() {
    let numbers = [4, 5, 7];
    let result = numbers.iter().position(|&n| &n > 0 && n != numbers[&n - 1] + 1);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

I get this compiler error regarding the `0`:

> expected reference, found integer
>
> help: consider borrowing here: `&0`

Basically I'm trying to do what this JavaScript does:

```js
numbers.find((n, i) => i && n != numbers[i - 1] + 1);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm assuming that `n` is the value and `&n` is the index.  If that isn't correct then how do I get the index inside the lamba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to look at each pair of two consecutive items in a slice the [`windows(2)` iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html?search=#method.windows):

```
fn find_non_consecutive(a: &[i32]) -> Option<i32> {
    a.windows(2).find(|x| x[0] + 1 != x[1]).map(|x| x[1])
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to write `return`?

Comment: @GirkovArpa No, since there is no trailing semicolon, the expression is the return value.

Comment: Hadn't seen `windows` before—very handy, will remember!

Answer (score 1):

`position` is used to search element. Since you need to check all elements in the array, use `enumerate` instead to access the element index and value:

```
fn main() {
    let numbers = [4, 5, 7];
    let result = numbers.iter().enumerate().filter_map(|(i, &n)| {
        if i > 0 && n != numbers[i-1] + 1 {
            Some(n)
        } else {
            None
        }
    });
    println!("{:?}", result.collect::<Vec<i32>>());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=24abcb50370614067eb0ad04cb472196).

If you only need to find the first such element, you can use `find_map` instead of `filter_map`:

```
fn main() {
    let numbers = [4, 5, 7];
    let result = numbers.iter().enumerate().find_map(|(i, &n)| {
        if i > 0 && n != numbers[i-1] + 1 {
            Some(n)
        } else {
            None
        }
    });
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the signature of [`Iterator::position`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position), you will see that its `predicate` closure parameter implements `FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool`.

In other words, your argument `&n` is of type `<numbers.iter() as Iterator>::Item` i.e. `&i32` (a reference to an element of `numbers`).  `Iterator::position` does not provide its `predicate` closure with access to the iteration index—as Psidom has demonstrated, that's what [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) does.

However, I would suggest that indexing the `numbers` array is not a very idiomatic way to solve this problem.  If nothing else, it can't be applied to other iterables more generally.  Perhaps instead take two iterators over the array, one an element further along, zip them up and pairwise compare their elements?

```
fn main() {
    let numbers = [4, 5, 7];
    
    let first = numbers.iter();
    let second = numbers.iter().skip(1);
    
    let result = first.zip(second)
        .find_map(|(&a, &b)| if b == a + 1 { None } else { Some(b) });
    
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=26f3c7d7aa7d95b0f65d313da687dbdb).

Answer (score 0):

I struggled hard to create a separate function that could be used as I wanted, so here is what ended up working:

```rust
fn find_non_consecutive(array_of_numbers: &[i32; 3]) -> Option<i32> {
    let result = array_of_numbers.iter().enumerate().find_map(|(i, &n)| {
        if i > 0 && n != array_of_numbers[i - 1] + 1 {
            Some(n)
        } else {
            None
        }
    });
    return result;
}

fn main() {
    let numbers: [i32; 3] = [4, 5, 7];
    let result = find_non_consecutive(&numbers);
    println!("{:?}", result); // Some(7)
}
```